# Programatically moving an inline onclick function to a JQuery click() function

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, click, submit

I'm hoping to be able to create a catch-all function which will allow me to dynamically set attributes on a legacy system. What I want to do is to create a JQuery click function which will disable the element and either submit the form or append the current onclick function to the JQuery click function. (It is assumed that the onclick code will handle the form)

So far I have

```
jQuery(element).click( function() {
onclick = (jQuery(this).attr('onclick') || jQuery(this).attr('onClick'));
if(form && !onclick) {
    jQuery(form).submit();
} else if (form && onclick) {
    jQuery(this).//how do I dynamically execute the onclick code using jquery?
}};
```

To the best of my knowledge this should be possible in javascript, however I can't find any similar threads.

**EDIT**

Thank you for the answers so far, however I need to clarify the problem further.

I need to be able to take the function currently in |tag "onclick=function()| and append that to the jQuery click function. This is necessary since I must unset the onclick attribute in order for the jQuery click event to fire, however I need to preserve the original functionality.

Comment: You can use `eval`... (dangerous)

Comment: Actually, you most likely don't need to unset the `onclick` property for click events to fire. Unless you have `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` (or `return false;`/`event.stopPropagation()` if it is a delegated event handler) in there.

Comment: Can you post an example of when an `onclick` attribute will affect jQuery's `.click(fn)` handling?

Comment: Apologies you are completely correct, the issue I was seeing was due to a typo in one of the id tags for a testing field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the native javascript onclick event like that:

```
this.click();
```

Comment: The simplest solution is often the one you never try, thank you for this solution and thanks to Fabricio for pointing out my error relating to onclick properties

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('element').click();
```

similar way of doing it for other events like change(), keyup(), etc..