# Inline onclick is overriding JQuery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

A follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522979/programatically-moving-an-inline-onclick-function-to-a-jquery-click-function)

**Edit**

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/liomry/G5KCW/)

As you can see if you run the code the button text does not change, the onclick is overriding the click function. If you remove the form id attribute from the function and the onclick attribute from the html tag the code works as expected (in a real scenario no onclick function implies a submit button rather than a button)

**End Edit**

I had thought that a typo was responsible for JQuery not firing the click() event when an inline event was specified, however I've run into the issue once more. Here's my code and the offending tag

```
<input id="submit1" type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true; doSubmit();" value="submit">


<script>myfunction('submit1', 'working', myformID)</script>

var myfunction = function(ID , text , formID) {
if(ID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(ID);
    if(formID) {
        var form = document.getElementById(formID);
    }
    if (element) {
        jQuery(element).click( function() {
            if(jQuery(this).attr('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
            jQuery(this).attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
            jQuery(this).attr('value' , processingText);
            onclick = (jQuery(this).attr('onclick') || jQuery(this).attr('onClick'));
            if(form && !onclick) {
                jQuery(form).submit();
            } 
            jQuery(this).click();
        });
    }
}
};
```

I'm using javascript to create a function which will disable submit buttons while keeping any onclick attribute working in case of a doSubmit, like in this case. In other cases where the form id is set and there isn't an existing onclick I submit the form. Therefore if there is an issue with the html tag I need a general way to fix it with JS.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can offer a JSfiddle version of your problem?

Comment: You're click handler is infinitely recursive...

Comment: Are you sure about that? The second time it is invoked it should return false due to the first if() in the click function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inline handler disables the button: `this.disabled=true;`

Then jQuery handler checks if it is disabled and returns if so:

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('disabled')) {
      return false;
}
```

There is, unfortunately, [no way to predict the order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) of event handlers execution for the same event on the same element.

As a quick fix, I can suggest this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/G5KCW/1/)

```
jQuery(element).click( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).attr('disabled-by-jquery')) {
        return false;
    }
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled-by-jquery' , 'disabled');
    jQuery(this).attr('value' , text);
    onclick = (jQuery(this).attr('onclick') || jQuery(this).attr('onClick'));
    if(form && !onclick) {
        jQuery(form).submit();
    } 
    jQuery(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately your demo seems to work once onload and then not work again, however I was already reconstructing the function in a similar way and the root issue is that event handlers are not called sequentially starting from outside the tag as I had thought so I'm accepting this answer. Thank you so much for your time